# c# xamarin slider sets to minimum every time I navigate to the sliders view

Tags: c#, xamarin, slider

I have a xamarin application for controlling projectors.

The app has multiple views with tabBar to navigate between the views.

The problem is that if I navigate to the view that contains some sliders, the sliders are set to the minimum value every time.

The sliders control the power gain for the LED's in the projector.

I tried to set the slider values in onappearing function of the view, but the sliders still jump to 0 before going to the wanted value.

The issue with this is that the sliders ValueChanged events gets fired, which causes the LED's to dim to 0

What can I do to prevent this from happening?

Comment: what happens if you set the value in the constructor?

Comment: That worked! I set the values in the constructor instead and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I set the values in the onAppearing instead of the constructor of the view. Thanks to Jason for pointing it out for me.